# Do drivers INF signed using self made certificates really dont work unless i go into testsigning mode on my windows?

Tags: powershell, driver, self-signed-certificate, inf

im sorry if this sounds stupid,

I discovered this PS2 Eyetoy driver online that someone created to use the eyetoy as a webcam on my PC, it works if i install the driver and go to testsigning mode on my windows 10, but i really want to use it with testsign mode off.

so i have been doing research on how to self sign my drivers and i followed this [tutorial](https://woshub.com/how-to-sign-an-unsigned-driver-for-windows-7-x64/)

I was able to sign the INF driver but, it still only works on testsigning mode. it said error code 53 when not on testsigning mode.

and i observed that other working drivers says "This driver is digitally signed" but mine says "This is signed by an Authenticode(TM) signature"

This method was done by New-SelfSignedCertificate feature of powershell then signed by windows WDK kit.

I saw another method using openSSL, will i get the same result

is it not possible to do this using self signed certificates ?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know about Windows signing specifically, but that's the nature of self-signed certificates in general: they are not trusted by anything. They are only really useful for testing and small-scale deployment (where they can be set to be trusted specifically on each client that needs it). So that they aren't accepted by Windows by default makes sense. Think about it: if Windows accepted self-signed certificates as valid, then anyone could sign (and therefore distribute/install) any drivers without any oversight, which defats the purpose of signed drivers.

Comment: It depends on the libraries you are using and the type of file.  Often pdf and xml files are signed.  With xml a CRC is added to the file using the certificate which is inserted in the document.  So if you are using a library that will give an exception if CRC is ignored than using a different library will work.  With PDF the certificate is used to encrypt the document and you cannot decrypt without the certificate.

Comment: thank you guys for the feedback i appreciate it , i was looking for a way, even if just in my specific unit that that driver is accepted , i guess yes self signing is meant for just testing

Comment: what libraries can you suggest bro

Comment: This is correct, you can only use self signed drivers in test signing mode. Signing for release mode requires submitting the driver to Microsoft which requires an extended validation certificate and a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so.. there's like an unlikely answer to your question, and then there are assured solutions to your actual problem.

Putting aside user-mode drivers, as I explained at lengths in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77175186/5994170) you can in fact self-sign whatever customized driver *packages* you want as long as the kernel *module* itself still retains a valid signature. But despite sounding good here, that's nonetheless a problem because I'm going to assume you are probably talking about [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20190906092041/http://metricrat.co.uk/ps2-eyetoy-on-windows-8-64-bit-working), the usual old Hercules Classic Webcam driver repurposed for different cameras. And it doesn't have a signature embedded into the .sys, but rather it is detached into the same .cat file that you are going to invalidate with your .inf edit.

The instructions argue that you can just play with the boot configuration, just **temporarily** enable test mode, and then calling it a day (and by all means you should still take a stab at it.. they did seem to report some degree of success even in W10, at least with its older versions?) but I'm skeptical that could continue to work even after you restore the boot settings to normal. I wouldn't definitively rule this out as impossible then (as I hint at the end of my first link above, maybe you could try to install the original [Vista 64](https://support.hercules.com/en/product/webcamclassic-en/) driver and then see if test-signing your modifications survives) but I wouldn't hold my breath.

For the [love of everything](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/kernel-mode-code-signing-policy--windows-vista-and-later-#signing-requirements-by-version) though, please disable Secure Boot while you do all this tinkering. I'm not sure how specifically it could interfere, but it's certainly not going to help.

---

With this said then, there are actually quite a few ways that this problem could be tackled (given this question is kinda worded about pulling this off at all *for you* rather than to ship to production or something). You can also:

- use 32-bit W10 (FWIW PAE patches exist to exceed the 4GB limit)
- try one of the many Driver Signature Enforcement overrider/bypass
- find another driver, from another OV51x camera to hack anew, or like [dshow-eyetoy](https://github.com/jackun/dshow-eyetoy)

Comment: i sincerely thank you for this bro <3