# Signing a 64-bit Windows driver for one machine I own

Tags: 64-bit, wdk, driver-signing

I need to run a driver on a single computer I own (with the possibility to add digital certificates) that isn't connected to the internet.

Microsoft stated in the detailed table in the [Driver Signing Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that we can sign 64-bit drivers with every trusted party when Secure Boot is disabled.

However, in the [Signing Driver for Public Release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552289%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page it looks like we can sign only with very specific parties. Is the definition of "Release" here relevant to me? I'm installing the driver on a specific machine that I own and am not releasing it to the entire world.

In addition, the [Driver Signing Requirements for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (that I don't know if it's updated) mentioned that "*Components must be signed by a certificate that Windows "trusts"*". What does it means? Does it include only Microsoft root-certified drivers, or just certificates that the local machine knows?

So, what are the exact requirements for the case when someone wants to run a driver on his own machine but not with the test self-signed certificate?

Comment: I think you are misreading the table on the "Driver Signing Policy" page.  It actually says that on x64, regardless of whether Secure Boot is enabled, kernel-mode drivers require a signature whose chain of trust goes back to "Standard roots trusted by CI".  Unfortunately, I don't know what CI means, do you?

Comment: Could you give more details about what you are trying to do?  Is this a USB driver?  Is it just an INF file, or is there also a SYS file?  What version of Windows does your computer run?

Comment: An NDIS driver with SYS file of course.

Comment: And, Windows Server 2008 R2 or Server 2012 - I can choose.

Answer (score 1):

There are many driver packages out there that don't have a SYS file (a kernel mode driver), and the signature requirements for them are less strict.  In your case, since you have a SYS file, the only type of signature that Windows (starting with Windows Vista 64-bit) will accept is a signature from a certificate whose chain of trust goes back to the Microsoft Code Verification Root.

Note: I haven't tested Windows Server 2008 or Server 2012; my experience is limited to the consumer versions of Windows.

Since you probably don't want to pay $200 for such a certificate, I would instead recommend [disabling driver signature enforcement](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/disabling-driver-signature-on-windows-8/disabling-signed-driver-enforcement-on-windows-8).  I believe this would allow you to run unsigned kernel modules, though I have not tried it.  It definitely lets you install unsigned driver packages, but that is a different issue.

I've done quite a lot of stuff with USB driver signing and wrote about my experiences in an article called [Practical Windows Code and Driver Signing](http://davidegrayson.nfshost.com/signing).

Comment: Is there no way to add a local certificate and to tell the computer I trust it for my driver?

Comment: If we are talking about Windows Vista 64-bit, Windows 7, or Windows 8, then my experience would indicate that's not possible.  You could try it though; you could use a tool like [XCA](http://xca.sourceforge.net/) to make your own certificate and install it in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities list using `certmgr.msc`.  It's not likely to work though; you will probably get some error like Code 52 telling you the signature of your driver is bad.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the tool listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175203/how-to-sign-my-driver-so-it-will-install-on-windows-7-64-bit).  It is [Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider](http://www.ngohq.com/?page=dseo).  Make sure you enable TestMode first.  I believe you have to reboot after test signing.